# Confirm Dialog when i close the browser?

Tags: javascript

i need to display confirm dialog box before close browser window using javascript or PHP.
the confirm box should come when i click the close button of browser. other wise don't display dialog.
please help me any.

Answer (score 23):

You should handle the onbeforeunload event...

```
function closeEditorWarning(){
    return 'Are you sure?'
}
window.onbeforeunload = closeEditorWarning;
```

Or use jquery, window.attachEvent / window.addEventListener to do it nicely

Comment: And you can return `undefined` from the callback, should you want to suppress the confirmation dialog, e.g. after verifying that the user hasn't started writing or editing something. However if you return `null` or `false`, IE shows a message asking you roughly if you want to *null* or *false*, oddly enough.

Answer (score 1):

`onunload` is not very useful (in my opinion) as you can't *do* anything with the `confirm`ation you're requesting (except maybe attempt to new another window with `window.open`, so `onbeforeunload` is more useful for this case.

Your better bet is `onbeforeunload`, which is great but won't work in Opera (though this usually isn't a deal breaker).

Like ivy said, it would look something like this:

```
<script>

    var userIsEditingSomething; // set this if something crazy happens
        oldOnBeforeUnload = window.onbeforeunload;

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        // attempt to handle a previous onbeforeunload
        if ('function' === typeof oldOnBeforeUnload) {
            var message = oldOnBeforeUnload();
            if ('undefined' !== typeof message) {
                if (confirm('string' === typeof message ? message : 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?')) {
                    return; // allow user to exit without further annoying pop-ups
                }
            }
        }
        // handle our own
        if (userIsEditingSomething) {
            return 'Are you sure you want to exit?';
        }
    };

</script>
```

Comment: AND it would trigger whenever the user left the page for whatever reason. NOT only when closing the browser

Comment: You're right. Although there are probably nice abstractions for this problem (jquery etc), years ago I used to test for the condition "( event.clientX < 0 || event.clientY < 0 )" to distinghuish between somebody pressing the window-close button (condition is true) and normal navigation actions (follow a link, submit a form, back, forward). This is not a fail-proof solution (e.g. ALT-F4 was not caught), so I hope somebody can provide you with a better solution.

Answer (score -3):

```
function doUnload()
{
  // use confirm dialog box here
   confirm("Window is closing...");

}

<body onunload="doUnload()">
```

Comment: onbeforeunload is the event handler to use.