# JavaScript redirect to feedback form when user decides to leave page?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm looking into a way to redirect visitors who decide to leave a page to a quick feedback form. By leaving I mean closing the tab - if they follow any of the links on the site, be it internal or external I don't want any redirects triggered, but if they decide to close the tab, or hit the back button, etc. - leave the site, I would very much like to redirect them to a quick feedback form and get their opinion on what they did not like.

So how can I go about this?

Comment: ***no***. Don't do it. It's a bad idea.

Comment: Why the downvotes? How is my question bad? It's not misleading, it's not irrelevant?

Comment: I did not vote you down, however here is a solution [Confirm Dialog when i close the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427714/confirm-dialog-when-i-close-the-browser) especially [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427714/confirm-dialog-when-i-close-the-browser/4427862#4427862) suggestion by me

Comment: @John: They're just doing you a favor, man. This is a really bad practice. Your question is legit, but it's like asking "How can I make my breath as bad as possible?"

Comment: @John, every time you hit the back button, type a new url in the address bar, perform a search with the browser's search bar (if it's separate from the location bar), use a bookmark, close a tab, or in any way leave a site without having clicked a link on that site, please smack yourself in the face. I'm not joking; try it for about 5 minutes of casual browsing, and you'll quickly realize that interrupting a user's browsing habits is **disruptive** and *painful*. Personally, I block sites that aggressively try to keep me from leaving.

Comment: I add an upvote. Maybe this is a bad practice, but the answer is fine and maybe other people really need an answer to this. And nowadays, with HTML5 online games and that, sure this can be handy for other purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You can't simply hijack the user's browser and force them to another page when they try to leave. Browsers have implemented prevention measures for this sort of intent years ago.

When the user opts to click back/forward or type a URL into the address bar while on your site, you can not redirect them somewhere else or prevent that action. You can, however, ask the user (via a standard dialog box in their browser that you can inject a text statement into in some cases) if they would like to stay on your site or navigate away.

What would be a better option for you would be to install something like Google Analytics:
http://www.google.com/analytics/

This will enable you to track your visitors activity in pretty grainy detail so you can see where they're leaving the site, how long they're staying, and where you may need to improve your site. This will give you much better feedback without intruding on the user's time or browsing experience. Furthermore programs like Analytics do not require the user to actively participate in giving you feedback (which you'd soon find out no one will). When someone decides to leave your site, they're gone. No amount of begging, pleading, or popups is going to make them stay. In fact, they'll probably just insure the user never comes back.

So take it from us, and use statistics tracking instead of interfering with the user's experience.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea, but here's how it's done. But beware, you'll be the scourge of all who visit your site. People hate this stuff. But if you insist on going into public places unshaven, with headlice and body odor, then look into:

```
window.onbeforeunload();
```

and

```
window.location();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not planning on using this as a permamnet feature - just to gather some feedback to improve my site. How else can I find out why they leave?!

Comment: Most who will be leaving won't even be human. They'll be bots from various search companies. A better way to determine what your customers want is to offer an array of items, see what gets attention, etc. Also, provide well-phrased opinion polls for passers-by ("Which do you like better...?").

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a function to `window.onbeforeunload`.

It's actually quite complicated to do what you want, because you have to make sure that you can identify what the user actually *did* to fire the event, which would mean making every single link on you page do something (and off the top of my head I'm not sure what that would be) that would allow you to identify it.

What you would have to do is essentially go through everything on your page that *shouldn't* trigger the form, make *all* of those things do something (maybe set a global variable?) then if that something hasn't been done, you can redirect people to your feedback form.

Users will hate you for it though...