# Add a javascript alert when a user tries to close the current tab in browser

Tags: javascript

I am working on asp.net(c#).I try to add a javascript alert when a user tries to close the current tab in browser.  The code is not working in Chrome.Please can any one help about this topic.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function close_window() {

    var r = confirm("Do you want to view other topics?");
    if (r == true) 
    {
        alert("You pressed OK!");
        var Url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
        window.location = Url;
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        window.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confirm Dialog when i close the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427714/confirm-dialog-when-i-close-the-browser)

Comment: This is bad practice. Please don't. It's annoying as hell to the user, and makes your site look like a seedy, backwater, advertising-peddling, 1996-era BLINK script kiddie brain fart.

Comment: @dda's rather strongly worded advice is generally worth heeding.  There are some reasons, for confirming a tab close--for instance, to confirm that text entered into a box is persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `()` when you're calling the function.

It should be:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function close_window {
```

Comment: Not quite.  This line sets the value of window.onbeforeunload, using the function literal syntax.  The parens are needed, the name of the function (`close_window`) is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, try this.

```
function close_window() {
...
}
window.onbeforeunload = close_window;
```

And yes--it's really bad practice.