# How to code an unclose-able pop up?

Tags: javascript, popup

As part of an artistic project that I am trying to do, I would like to implement an unclose-able pop up. 
I am working on the concept of a box (that I have already made in CSS) that when clicked on opens a pop up that is unclose-able unless the user does what is required (in this case: drawing on a canvas). I would like that there be a button that when clicked:
1) closes the pop up.
2) forces the download of the drawing to the computer.

I have managed to make a pop up (with the right size, in the right placement etc). I have also made a button that when clicked, closes the pop up. However, I still cannot seem to make the popup stay when the user tries to click the red X in the corner... I have noticed that uncloseable pop-ups don't really work in Chrome, but I would still like it to be theoretically unclose-able because it is vital to understanding my art.

How can I make it so that it keeps coming back unless the user submits his/her "drawn art"?

Thanks in advance! Very appreciated. If the code works, I will definitely be putting your name on it.

PS: If anyone knows of any code that will force the download of the drawing from the canvas, that would be VERY much appreciated. Right now, I can only go to another page where we have to right click --> save image as --> etc

Thanks! :)

Comment: Neither of those things are possible unless you have the users download and install a browser extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Juhana :) Is there anyway to make a pop up that keeps coming back if the x is clicked?

Comment: No. All this is related to browser security--if it would be possible to create windows that can't be closed, you'd have ten of them open right now advertising Viagra. The same thing with sending files without user consent (think about viruses). Your best bet is either simulating a popup in the browser window as Brandon suggests, or showing a [confirmation dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427714/confirm-dialog-when-i-close-the-browser) when the window is about to be closed.

Comment: Ok, thanks! At least I know now that it's not going to be possible and I can start thinking about changing my idea. Thanks again :)

Comment: I know this isn't unclosable really (it can be closed by ctrl-w) but if you make a real popup window (onclick) that follows your cursor (so you can't click X) it would be hard for people who don't know ctrl-W to close it without quitting the whole browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really create an "unclose-able" popup.  You could, however, overlay the entire page with a lightbox.  As a proof of concept I've thrown this together with the assistance of jQuery.  It's very rudimentary and would need quite a bit of namespacing/cleaning up/etc. http://jsfiddle.net/CJCQQ/

CSS:

```
#page-cover {
    background-color: #888; 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%
}
#uncloseable-lightbox {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 500px;
}
#uncloseable-lightbox button { position: absolute }
#uncloseable-lightbox #close-button { top: 10px; right: 10px;}
#uncloseable-lightbox #click-first-button { bottom: 10px; left: 10px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="page-cover">
    <div id="uncloseable-lightbox">
        <button id="close-button">close</button>
        <button id="click-first-button">Click Me First</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="open-button">Open</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var outerThis = this, canClose = false;
    $('#open-button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#page-cover').show();
    });

    $('#close-button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(outerThis.canClose) {
            $('#page-cover').hide();
            outerThis.canClose = false;
        }
    });

    $('#click-first-button').on('click', function (e) {
        outerThis.canClose = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll give a lightbox a try!

Comment: Somehow I grabbed an older iteration from jfiddle.  Here's the actual version: http://jsfiddle.net/CJCQQ/

Comment: `You can't really create an "unclose-able" popup.` I'm afraid your statement is not true. I just came across a website, which opened two popups, and one of them can not be closed. Video proof: https://youtu.be/GoqjZ-JjPlE (using Edge on Windows 10). Not sure how they did it, but they probably exploit a bug in the browser to ignore the close events.