# Adding a script in xhtml page for displaying a warning message on closing a browser window doesnot work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am working on jsf2 and primefaces. I want to display a message, when a user clicks on close button of browser. As per one of the answer given here in stackoverflow I have added the following script in  tag

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
                    e = e || window.event;

                    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
                    if (e) {
                        e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
                    }

                    // For Safari
                    return 'Sure?';
 </script>
```

But its not working. I have also tried adding the CDATA and still not working.

Comment: Link the answer that you found in your question. Are you sure your script is executed? Set a breakpoint in an javascript debugger or just add alerts at different places in your `<script>` area.

Comment: This question was answered here, and it works fine for me:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427714/confirm-dialog-when-i-close-the-browser>